# Microsoft Office 2011 is sluggish

Tags: imac, ms-office

I am a the tech support guy for a small church. we just purchased Microsoft office 2011 for mac.

we have noticed it drastically slows our imac (not sure on the specs atm) when one of the office products is running.

has anyone else noticed this or is it something on just our machine

Comment: @mjrider: We need more information to go by to help. What type of iMac do you have? Have you looked in Activity Monitor to be sure it is MS Office?

Comment: I am relatively new to the mac platform so I have not tried the activity monitor (but I will when I go in next)

Comment: When you get in, go into About This Mac in the Apple menu and get the processor and memory shown in there. Activity Monitor will show all of the processes that are running in the system. There are other things like Spotlight that can slow things down as well, but AM will tell you for sure what's going on. Also noting when things get sluggish would help as well.

Comment: I would recommend trying iWork, as it does everything an average joe would need plus more.  It's dead simple to use/learn, and personally, I feel it's better than word.

Comment: @debug for someone who just purchased Office 2011, I wouldn't.

Comment: it isn't compleatly out of the question...it is kinda annoing ...I am kinda wondering if anyone else has had the problem...not what to replace it with

Comment: @koiyu: I recommended trying it out,as you can always download a free trial to see if its something worth pursuing.  I put very little hope into MS products for OSX, but that's just me. Also, he is using it for a church iMac, so maybe it would be something easier to learn..I'm sure they're not using it for the advanced features MS word has to offer..just another option.  I've never heard anyone not liking iWork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you can try :

1) Make sure you have the latest updates installed.  Office 2011 has been updated since release, so it pays to ensure the latest versions of all applications are installed.

2) Perform a Repair Permission on your Macs hard disk.  This has been known to cure slowdowns in a a few Applications including Office 2011.  Repair Permissions is a feature of Disk Utility found in the Utility folder in Applications.